# A local variable of calling function is accessible in the called function

Tags: linux, bash, shell

Recently while working I noticed this behavior of local variables. I wrote this piece of code to simplify my doubt.

```
foo () {
    echo "This is moo : $MOO_VAR"
}

moo () {
    local MOO_VAR="Hi MOO!"
    foo
}

echo "calling moo."
moo
```

I can't understand how function `foo` can access the value of local variable `MOO_VAR`of function `moo`, although `foo` cannot change the value of `MOO_VAR` . I can't find any explanation for this behavior. Can somebody explain why this happens ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is [documented](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/localvar.html#FTN.AEN18568) behaviour of bash. It would seem that local really just means, restore this variable to its previous state at the end of the function. Due to how variables are implemented in bash (stored in a global namespace), this means the variables cannot be hidden from children without first unsetting the variable before each function call and then reinstating it afterwards.

Comment: But you can define a `local` variable in `foo` of the same name, its value will be restored at the end of the function.

Comment: Yes, I know that. But why is the local variable of `moo` accessible to `foo`. Shouldn't the scope of `MOO_VAR` be inside `moo` itself.

Comment: Dunes, so if I change the value of `MOO_VAR` inside `foo` , it will change its value as it is stored in global namespace, and when the function ends it will just reinitialize it to its original value so that its usage in `moo` remains unaffected ?

Comment: @molecule Because bash is a scripting language, not a fully fledged programming language. If you want a fresh scope for each function call then try something like python.

Comment: Put another way, `bash` is a dynamically scoped language.